# simplifying- if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, simplify, python-turtle

I have this code right here but I don't understand how to simplify the code, does anyone have an idea on how to simplify codes like these

```
if ball.ycor() > 340:
    ball.sety(340)
    ball.ycoor *= -1

if ball.ycor() < -340:
    ball.sety(-340)
    ball.ycoor *= -1

if ball.xcor() > 490:
    ball.goto(0,0)
    ball.xcoor *= -1
    scoreboard_a += 1
    score.clear()
    score.write("{}           {}".format(scoreboard_a,scoreboard_b), font=("Arial",104,"normal"))

if ball.xcor() < -490:
    ball.goto(0,0)
    ball.xcoor *= -1
    scoreboard_b += 1
    score.clear()
    score.write("{}           {}".format(scoreboard_a,scoreboard_b), font=("Arial",104,"normal"))


if (ball.xcor() > 440 and ball.xcor() < 450) and ball.ycor() < block_b.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > block_b.ycor() - 40:
    ball.setx(440)
    ball.xcoor *= -1
   

if (ball.xcor() < -440 and ball.xcor() > -450) and ball.ycor() > block_a.ycor() - 40 and ball.ycor() < block_a.ycor() + 40:
    ball.setx(-440)
    ball.xcoor *= -1
```

Comment: Try using `if-else` statements, so that you don't have multiple single `if`.

Comment: Looks like a simple game engine of a football game... I find the code simple enough to understand. What kind of simplification do you need? Which part of the code confuses you?

Comment: @a121 I have to disagree with your edit. What makes you think he/she want to specifically simplfiy the if's?@Beginner12345 makes no mention about this in his question text. In my opinion he/she would need to clarify that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should combine mutually exclusive possibilities with `if-else` statements. My first inclination was to evaluate `ball.ycor()` and `ball.xcor()` once with the following on the assumption that successive calls did not return different values:

```
x_coor = ball.xcor()
y_coor = ball.ycor()
```

But I noticed the expression `ball.ycoor *= -1`, and it suggested that this could effect the return value from a subsequent call to `ball.ycor()`. So I decided to not attempt to optimize out these calls:

```
if ball.ycor() > 340:
    ball.sety(340)
    ball.ycoor *= -1
elif ball.ycor() < -340:
    ball.sety(-340)
    ball.ycoor *= -1

if ball.xcor() > 490:
    ball.goto(0,0)
    ball.xcoor *= -1
    scoreboard_a += 1
    score.clear()
    score.write("{}           {}".format(scoreboard_a,scoreboard_b), font=("Arial",104,"normal"))
elif ball.xcor() < -490:
    ball.goto(0,0)
    ball.xcoor *= -1
    scoreboard_b += 1
    score.clear()
    score.write("{}           {}".format(scoreboard_a,scoreboard_b), font=("Arial",104,"normal"))
elif (-450 < ball.xcor() < -440) and ball.ycor() > block_a.ycor() - 40 and ball.ycor() < block_a.ycor() + 40:
    ball.setx(-440)
    ball.xcoor *= -1
elif (440 < ball.xcor() < 450) and ball.ycor() < block_b.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > block_b.ycor() - 40:
    ball.setx(440)
    ball.xcoor *= -1
```

Note that `if x > y and x < z:` can be rewritten as `if y < x < z:`

Comment: thanks @Booboo helped me understand on how to simplify it up

Answer (score 1):

You can sandwich a value between multiple comparison operators. You can use an `f` string to directly pass the values into the curly braces.

```
if ball.ycor() > 340:
    ball.sety(340)
    ball.ycoor *= -1

if ball.ycor() < -340:
    ball.sety(-340)
    ball.ycoor *= -1

if ball.xcor() > 490:
    ball.goto(0, 0)
    ball.xcoor *= -1
    scoreboard_a += 1
    score.clear()
    score.write(f"{scoreboard_a}           {scoreboard_b}", font=("Arial", 104, "normal"))

if ball.xcor() < -490:
    ball.goto(0, 0)
    ball.xcoor *= -1
    scoreboard_b += 1
    score.clear()
    score.write("{scoreboard_a}           {scoreboard_b}", font=("Arial", 104, "normal"))

if 450 > ball.xcor() > 440 and block_b.ycor() - 40 < ball.ycor() < block_b.ycor() + 40:
    ball.setx(440)
    ball.xcoor *= -1
   

if -450 < ball.xcor() < -440 and block_a.ycor() + 40 > ball.ycor() > block_a.ycor() - 40:
    ball.setx(-440)
    ball.xcoor *= -1
```

Also, you might want to store the `font` value into a variable so that you can use it by using the variable, like `font = ("Arial", 104, "normal")`, and then

```
score.write(f"{scoreboard_a}           {scoreboard_b}", font=font)
```

Furthermore, if you can your code to be more efficient, only use the `if` statement for the first statement, and use `elif` for the rest. That way, python wouldn't need to bother to check the other statements once it find one where the condition meets.

Comment: Agree with MadMike's comment here. You only changed a detail in the reporting. The code does not look easier to read.. Personally I would create 3 separate procedures for ball X, ball height and the block change corrections.. but that gives more code..  so..

Comment: @Goodies The efficiency improved in my answer. Don't you think `450 > ball.xcor() > 440` is easier to read compared with `(ball.xcor() > 440 and ball.xcor() < 450)`?

Comment: Nope I don't think a different comparison improves anything.. but I did not downvote your anwer.. your solution is better, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: @Goodies Why not? Don't you think `450 > ball.xcor() > 440` is the simplified version of `(ball.xcor() > 440 and ball.xcor() < 450)`? Oh, you edited your first comment...

Comment: It all fits on a single page... you should see my java code I'm forced to work with :-/

Comment: @Goodies Than I'm confused. If simplified code doesn't answer the question, what would answer the question then?

Comment: @MadMike Interested.

Comment: My tip: Beginner12345 could create a seperate module and a separate function or method for this code, When it is tested properly, he does not need to look at it too often.. :)

Comment: Oh, that makes sense :)

Comment: @Ann Zen,this is all comments.. and a matter of opinion.I did not downvote your answer, but I also cannot acknowledge it as the right answer. Maybe Stackoverflow will do that..

Comment: My guess is he/she doesn't know what the code does. But isn't stead of posting a description of what the problem is or where he/she has problems to understand the code. We are requested to simplify it ... smells like someones homework too.

Comment: @MadMike Stack Overflow will do what?

Comment: @AnnZen Helping out with Homework? It depends: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: It's [not a close reason](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51199789#51199789)...

Comment: I agree.. maybe a teacher complained about this code ? maybe object oriented approach was asked ? suppose you would have a Ball class.. and a Field class. you could replace 8 lines of this test by calling ball.MoveWhenOutside(field) or something like that..

Comment: @Goodies I agree with you. We really need to know in what way the code needs to be simplified. AnnZen answer is good. For my own taste the code was okay to begin with.

Comment: @AnnZen Ty for the chat link.